# What does $this->dispatch('/') means in zend test

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop

I am writing unit test for zend project,
I want to know

```
<?php

    class IndexControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase
    {

        public function testHomePage() {
            $this->dispatch('/');

        }
    }
```

The ControllerTestcase.php extends Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
    require_once 'Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php';

    class ControllerTestCase 
        extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase 
    {
        protected $application;

        public function setUp() {
            $this->bootstrap = array($this,'appBootstrap');
            parent::setUp();

        }

        public function appBootstrap() {
            $this->application = 
                new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV,
                                     APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/application.ini');

            $this->application->bootstrap();


        }
    }
```

what does $this->dispatch('/'); means? does this mean forward to request to root of the application?

Comment: @Flavius I already said I am very newbie to zend framework together with phpunit, I just need some help not just criticism！

Comment: Don't take criticism too harshly, it's part of the journey. Just keep asking questions and you'll get where you're going.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz Thank you  I got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comment to this method:

```
 * Dispatch the MVC
 *
 * If a URL is provided, sets it as the request URI in the request object.
 * Then sets test case request and response objects in front controller,
 * disables throwing exceptions, and disables returning the response.
 * Finally, dispatches the front controller.
```

http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/tags/release-1.9.8/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php

Comment: You can find it easily self, by using some IDE (e.g. NetBeans or PhpStorm).

Comment: An IDE should not be a replacement for competence. First learn to do it manually, then jump to an IDE when you are already a competent programmer and your boss asks you to be more productive. That's an IDE first and foremost. The rest are (wanted) side-effects of using it.

Comment: +1 for finding it for themselves, which is essentially what I suggested. :)

Comment: @Flavius, competence and learning from an IDE are not mutually exclusive.  And to suggest that people learn to program on notepad before "graduating" to the privilege of using an IDE is just silly.

Answer (score 1):

In object oriented programming, when a class extends another, it inherits the methods (or functions) of its parent class (the class it is extending).

You can use `$this->method` to call a classes methods from within itself or its descendents (other classes that extend it).

given that `dispatch` is not defined in `IndexControllerTest`, it must be a function of `ControllerTestCase` (which `IndexControllerTest` extends) and it is passing the string `'/'` to it.

Have a look for the class `ControllerTestCase` and there will be a function called `dispatch`, you can see what that is doing there.

Comment: I think he asking not about how dispatch() will be called (and where this method had declared), but what "/" argument does mean.

Comment: I really want to know what '/' argument mean.

Comment: If you follow my answer, you will find out.